# Looping through rows with condition using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate the rows with condition like in below dataframe by creating new column **New_Course**.

What I am looking for is when **status= New and Status1=7** then create new column **New_COurse** in below df and mark the sequence of course till the loop detects same condition and rest should be entered as 0 meaning if **status= new and Status1 =0** then it should be marked as 0 till next iteration.

| ID | Status | status1 | New_Course |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | New | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 1 |
| 1 | New | 7 | 2 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | New | 7 | 3 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 3 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 3 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 3 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |
| 1 | New | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | Existing Course | 7 | 0 |

Comment: Please post your code for df creation, so that it will be easy for us to test our solutions, thank you.

Comment: Hi @RavinderSingh13 I actually created that column in power query excel. But could not do it in python. And it is very slow for processing that condition for 1 million rows in excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to number the instances of 'New' and Status1 = 7 using a mask `m1` and [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html#pandas-dataframe-cumsum).

Mask the 'New' and Status1 = 0 locations and set those to 0.

Then use [ffill](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html#pandas-series-ffill) to fill the values in between.

```
# Mask Where New and Status1 7
m1 = df['Status'].eq('New') & df['status1'].eq(7)
# Mask Where New and Status1 0
m2 = df['Status'].eq('New') & df['status1'].eq(0)

# Set Group Values For m1
df.loc[m1, 'New_Course'] = m1.cumsum()
# Set m2 to 0
df.loc[m2, 'New_Course'] = 0
# FFill the values
df['New_Course'] = df['New_Course'].ffill().astype(int)

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
    ID           Status  status1  New_Course
0    1              New        7           1
1    1  Existing Course        7           1
2    1  Existing Course        7           1
3    1              New        7           2
4    1              New        0           0
5    1  Existing Course        7           0
6    1              New        0           0
7    1              New        0           0
8    1              New        0           0
9    1  Existing Course        7           0
10   1              New        0           0
11   1              New        7           3
12   1  Existing Course        7           3
13   1  Existing Course        7           3
14   1  Existing Course        7           3
15   1              New        0           0
16   1  Existing Course        7           0
17   1  Existing Course        7           0
18   1  Existing Course        7           0
19   1  Existing Course        7           0
20   1              New        0           0
21   1  Existing Course        7           0
22   1  Existing Course        7           0
23   1              New        0           0
24   1  Existing Course        7           0
```

Comment: Thank You. I was unaware that condition could work like this. I was using lambda function for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it:

```
# create the increasing new course
df['New_Course'] = (df.Status.eq('New') & df.status1.eq(7)).cumsum()

# set new course with Status=new and status1=0 as 0
df.loc[df.Status.eq('New') & df.status1.ne(7), 'New_Course'] = 0

# set other rows as NaN
df.loc[df.Status.ne('New'), 'New_Course'] = None

# forward fill NaNs
df.New_Course = df.New_Course.ffill().astype(int)
df

    ID           Status  status1  New_Course
0    1              New        7           1
1    1  Existing Course        7           1
2    1  Existing Course        7           1
3    1              New        7           2
4    1              New        0           0
5    1  Existing Course        7           0
6    1              New        0           0
7    1              New        0           0
8    1              New        0           0
9    1  Existing Course        7           0
10   1              New        0           0
11   1              New        7           3
12   1  Existing Course        7           3
13   1  Existing Course        7           3
14   1  Existing Course        7           3
15   1              New        0           0
16   1  Existing Course        7           0
17   1  Existing Course        7           0
18   1  Existing Course        7           0
19   1  Existing Course        7           0
20   1              New        0           0
21   1  Existing Course        7           0
22   1  Existing Course        7           0
23   1              New        0           0
24   1  Existing Course        7           0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension.

```
from itertools import groupby
new_course = [0 if key == 0 else 1 for (key, group) in groupby(df.status1) for _ in group]
df['new_course'] = new_course
```

Is this what you need?